# WPF ValidationRule Dropping Decimal Point

Tags: c#, wpf, decimal, tryparse

I have the following XAML:

```
            <TextBox Name="LevyWageLimitFormulaID_TextBox"
                     Width="150"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedStateRule.LevyRule.WageLimitFormulaID" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <vm:NumericValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

The validator is defined as such:

```
/// <summary>
/// Numeric Validator to make sure value is numeric
/// </summary>
public class NumericValidator : ValidationRule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validate field is blank or contains only numbers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="cultureInfo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        Decimal _number;
        if (!Decimal.TryParse((value as string), out _number) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value must be numeric");
        }

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

This works fine until I try to type a decimal number.  If I enter `'10.'` in the textbox the decimal point gets dropped (the user never sees the decimal point appear in the textbox).  If I enter `'100'` and then move the cursor manually and add a decimal point to make the value `'10.0'` the validation works and the decimal point remains.

I know this is caused by the `out _number` portion of the `Decimal.TryParse` in conjunction with the validation being performed as soon as the property is changed (which is one of the requirements), but is there a way to fix this method such that I can type `'10.'` and have the decimal point remain in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't caused by your ValidationRule. If you temporarily remove the ValidationRule you will experience the same behaviour.

The issue is that the `decimal` source property *cannot* be set to something else than a `decimal` value and "10." is indeed not a valid `decimal` value.

What you could do is to bind to a wrapper `string` property that sets the `decimal` property:

```
//add this wrapper property to your class:
private string _wrapper;
public string Wrapper
{
    get { return _wrapper; }
    set
    {
        _wrapper = value;
        decimal d;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(_wrapper, out d))
            WageLimitFormulaID = d;
    }
}

private decimal _wageLimitFormulaID;
public decimal WageLimitFormulaID
{
    get { return _wageLimitFormulaID; }
    set { _wageLimitFormulaID = value; }
}
```

---

```
<TextBox Name="LevyWageLimitFormulaID_TextBox"
                     Width="150"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedStateRule.LevyRule.Wrapper" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <vm:NumericValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in general, this approach is not very useful. You should add wrapper for all properties. I guess it would be better to find "Decimal text box" control and use it everywhere you need binding to decimal values.

Comment: The only difference then is that "this approach" would be implemented in the control. You still can't set a decimal property to something else than a decimal which is the main point here.